# Import ImgProc and Core OpenCv modules only in Android

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing

I want to use **OpenCv library** in Android. But the problem is I don't want all the OpenCv modules built into my APK (since it makes the APK size large). I only want to use the **Imgproc** and the **Core** modules of OpenCV since I only need to do some image processing through my app/sdk (and this will make the apk much smaller in size). Is there a way to only import these two modules in my app/sdk. Thanks :)

Comment: did you got the ans ?